# Why do I get different results when calling from different file locations?

Tags: python, class, dynamic

I want to load `class` `dynamically`.

I have three files, `MainClass.py`, `MyClassA.py` and `MyClassB.py`. Why do I run `different results` from `MainClass.py` and `MyClassA.py`?
When running from `MainClass.py`, the result is:

```
B
```

Which is the result I want.
When running from `MyClassA.py`, the result is :

```
MainClass.property is None!
```

The code of MainClass.py is as follows:

```
from MyClassA import MyClassA, main

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyClassA.property = 'B'
    main()
```

The code of MyClassA.py is as follows:

```
import importlib


class MyClassA:
    property = None


def main():
    module_name = 'MyClass' + MyClassA.property
    class_name = module_name
    module_object = importlib.import_module(module_name)
    module_class_object = getattr(module_object, class_name)

    '''
    The reason why I quote MyClassA here is that because module_class_object is dynamically loaded,
    PyCharm cannot automatically prompt related content when writing code,
    and the upper class is subject to the first one,
    so I put MyClassA in the second referenced for my convenience PyCharm writes code.
    '''
    
    class MainClass(module_class_object, MyClassA):
        pass

    if MainClass.property is None:
        print('MainClass.property is None!')
    else:
        print(MainClass.property)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyClassA.property = 'B'
    main()
```

The code of MyClassB.py is as follows:

```
from MyClassA import MyClassA


class MyClassB(MyClassA):
    pass
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because the `MyClassA` object which gets imported in `MyClassB.py` is *different* from `MyClassA.py:MyClassA` when calling that script as the *main script*. The reason is that Python will create a *new* module object for the import (which is distinct from the [`__main__` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html#name-main)). You can verify that by adding `print(MainClass.mro())` after the class definition which will output the following:

```py
# python MainClass.py
[<class 'MyClassA.main.<locals>.MainClass'>,
 <class 'MyClassB.MyClassB'>,
 <class 'MyClassA.MyClassA'>,
 <class 'object'>]

# python MyClassA.py
[<class '__main__.main.<locals>.MainClass'>,
 <class 'MyClassB.MyClassB'>,
 <class 'MyClassA.MyClassA'>,
 <class '__main__.MyClassA'>,
 <class 'object'>]
```

Now because you define `class MainClass(module_class_object, MyClassA)`, the `module_class_object` appears earlier in the [MRO](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-method-resolution-order). I.e. when you ask for `MainClass.property` it will find that attribute in `<class 'MyClassA.MyClassA'>` rather than `<class '__main__.MyClassA'>` which is the class you modified.

On the other hand, when running `python MainClass.py`, then both modules (`__main__` and `MyClassB.py`) import *the same* module object `MyClassA` since it is cached in [`sys.modules`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.modules). Hence all changes to objects defined in this module are shared across all other modules that use the module `MyClassA`.

Comment: Is there any way to get the result of ‘B’ even when running ’MyClassA.py’? I tried to ’import importlib’ later, but it didn't seem to get the result I wanted.

Comment: @jaried Without knowing the bigger picture, it is difficult to suggest an appropriate solution. Perhaps you could provide some additional information why you need this dynamic import and definition of `MainClass`? It seems that a straightforward approach would be to separate the `main` function and `MyClassA` into two different modules and import `MyClassA` into the module defining `main`.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. After I moved the `main()` function from `MyClassA` to `MainClass`, it was the result I wanted.