# How to dynamically import the class？

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I have four files: `main.py`, `MainClass.py`, `SigClass.py`, and `MyClassC.py`. The entry is `main.py`. I rewrite the function `function_a` of `MyClassA` in `MyClassC`, so I need to set `SigClass` in `main.py` `sig` attribute, so MainClass inherits `MyclassC` and `MyclassA` in `MainClass.py`. My code is as follows, which does not inherit the function `function_a` of `MyClassC`.

[This question explains why the weird class in the middle is used.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69466953/why-do-i-get-different-results-when-calling-from-different-file-locations)

I have tried many methods, but I can only achieve my goal in `TempClass` in the `main()` space of `MainClass.py`, but in `__main__` of `MainClass.py` Space can't do it.

How can the `TempClass` in the `main()` space be referenced in other files? I really can’t think of a way.

How can I modify the code? Or is there any other way?

The sample code is as follows:

main.py:

```
from MainClass import SigClass, main

SigClass.sig = "MyClassC"
main()
from MainClass import MainClass

MainClass.function_a()
print(MainClass.property)
```

MainClass.py:

```
from time import time
from SigClass import SigClass
import importlib

sig = SigClass.sig


class MyClassA:
    sig = '1'
    property = 'A'

    @classmethod
    def function_a(cls):
        cls.property = 'A'


class MainClass:
    pass


def main():
    module_name = SigClass.sig
    class_name = SigClass.sig
    module_object = importlib.import_module(module_name)
    module_class_object = getattr(module_object, class_name)

    class TempClass(module_class_object, MyClassA):
        pass

    global MainClass

    MainClass = TempClass
```

SigClass.py

```
class SigClass:
    sig = 1
```

MyClassC.py

```
from MainClass import MyClassA


class MyClassC(MyClassA):
    @classmethod
    def function_a(cls):
        cls.property = 'c'
        pass
```

Comment: *why* do you want to do this?  Dynamic inheritence is *sometimes* needed, but in general dynamic programming is a pretty big way to introduce bugs.  If you can avoid creating and modifying classes at runtime your code will be a *lot* easier to read/maintain

Comment: @2e0byo Because I need to rewrite the module with different functions, the program will be very difficult to read if the if condition is used to judge, and it will be easier to read the inherited rewrite function. Maybe my understanding is incorrect.

Comment: I really think it would be a good idea to specify, as briefly as you can, what the use-case is for this later.  when I first read it I thought you just wanted to replace a method in one class with one in a sub-class (in which case you don't need to anything other than *define* the method); then I thought you were building some kind of dynamic model which had to adapt itself to changing third-party data structures, then I read it again and just got even more confused by what you mean by `__main__` space (do you just mean module scope?)

Comment: Note that I'm not saying there isn't a good, answerable question here, but before I jump in and point out that you can 'access your temp class' which you define inside a function (main()) from outside of that function by binding it to a name with larger scope, I want to work out *why* you want to do something so unusual as defining a class inside a function and then throwing it away

Comment: Is there a reason why you cannot use `from MyClassC import MyClassC; main(MyClassC)`  (or even `main('MyClassC')`, if you want to keep the dynamic import) instead of using this weird intermediary `SigClass`?

Comment: @2e0byo  `__main__` refers to `__main__` in `MainClass.py`.
I need to rewrite a lot of functions in `MyClassC` to put them together more convenient to maintain. Similarly, I also need to load `MyClassD`, `MyClassE`, `MyClassF` according to different situations, which are similar to `MyClassC` and rewrite many functions.

Comment: @Jasmijn This is a good idea, but if there are a lot of objects that need to be loaded to choose one of them, I only think of using IF, which would be a lot of steps.

Comment: what _is_ `__main__` in MainClass.py?  I know what module-level scope is, and I know what `__name__ == "__main__"` is, but I don't know what the (function?) `__main__` which somehow exists in that module without actually being defined is...

Comment: @jaried 'lots of objects to be loaded' it would really help if you edited you question to say what `main` is actually supposed to *do*, and why you need to load these objects.  Instantising an object at runtime based upon some dynamic condition is definitely possible without weird intermediate classes (e.g. just using `getattr` on the module, or maintaining a manual mapping in a dict).  What *are* these classes, and how does your code decide which it needs (and what does it then use it for)?

Comment: Incidentally if the only objection to some non-dynamic-class way of doing this is not wanting lots of if statements, the usual pythonic solution pre 3.10 is just to use a dict of `{case: function}` and do something like `{1: func_1, 2: func_2}.get(key, default)()`.  if you can use 3.10 there are now neater ways

Comment: If you have different question now, you should post it separately rather than trying to "reuse" this one.

Comment: @martineau ok，I changed my question back

Comment: @2e0byo I can only use python 3.7.

Comment: @2e0byo use a manual mapping is a good idea.

Comment: @2e0byo My question explains why the weird class in the middle is used. ： https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69466953/why-do-i-get-different-results-when-calling-from-different-file-locations

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @2e0byo's tips, I think the following code best meets my needs:

Import `MyClassC` according to `SigClass.sig`, and `SigClass.sig` is also the most important part of `MainClass`.

```
class BaseClass:
    name = None
    pass


class SigClass(BaseClass):
    name = "SigClass"
    sig = 1


class MyClassA(BaseClass):
    name = "MyClassA"
    property = 'A'
    sig = 'a'

    @classmethod
    def function_a(cls):
        pass


class MyClassC(MyClassA):
    name = "MyClassC"
    property = "C"
    sig = 'c'

    @classmethod
    def function_a(cls):
        pass


class ClassCollections(BaseClass):
    classes: dict = {}

    @classmethod
    def add_class(cls, class_to_add: type(BaseClass)):
        cls.classes[class_to_add.name] = class_to_add


SigClass.sig = "MyClassC"
ClassCollections.add_class(MyClassA)
ClassCollections.add_class(MyClassC)


class MainClass(SigClass, ClassCollections.classes[SigClass.sig], MyClassA):
    pass


print(MainClass.sig)
```

```
MyClassC
```